# GnuPG v2.0.12 (MingW32) JAVA Encryption

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Pearl script when used for encryption with key version - GnuPG v2.0.12 (MingW32) , produces the encrypted file with below output format:

Scenario 1

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.8 (SunOS)

hQELA3Hk..............................

..............................................

................................K56VUHIr

-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

But the JAVA API (Bouncy Castle or others) generates the output file as :

Scenario 2

```
„ŒTÆ£¹ÉþRýžípó1+B¿ºp–å¿‘I¨........„ŒTÆ£¹ÉþRýžípó1+
```

No headers or footer.

but the same data when encrypted with same key on free encryption site(https://www.igolder.com/pgp/encryption/ ) showed the same result as scenario 1.

If the decryption is to happen as earlier(in pearl) and encryption is to be upgraded i.e. through JAVA .
How can we make this happen using JAVA APIs ..which are not generating the right output it seems ??

Or I may be wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is known as "ASCII-armored" -- i.e. it is a BASE64 representation of the actual binary encrypted output.  The second one is the binary form, which looks garbled as you sent it to the terminal.

I believe you need to use an `ArmoredOutputStream` when writing the encrypted output.

Comment: You are a star Jim. I set armor to true it is working now.
Another thing is that the header shows:
Version: BCPG v1.48

Whereas it should be :
Version: GnuPG v1.4.8 (SunOS)

??

Comment: My Google-fu is strong today :-)